# Finding amount of times item has been repeated in an unsorted 2D array - Java

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I'm just practicing with 2D arrays and currently I am trying to locate the position both for rows and columns of a given number. The array is unsorted.

I can fill the array with random numbers from 10-20. It knows the amount of times the number has been found repeated but once again for each item matching the number selected by the user, I need to print the coordinates of the item and that's exactly what I'm missing.

Here is my code :

```
   int cont = 0;
   int num;

   public void number (){

        matrixnn = new int [10][10];

        num = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Pick a number from 10-20 "));

       for(int i = 0; i < matrixnn.length; i++ ){
           for (int j = 0; j < matrixnn[i].length; j++){

               matrixnn [i][j] = (int)(Math.random()*(20-10+1)+10);

               if(num == matriznx[i][j]){
                   cont++;    
               }   
            System.out.print(matrixnn[i][j]+" ");           
       }     
         System.out.println();
    }

        System.out.println("\nThe number selected "+num+" has been found "+cont+" times."); 
        System.out.println("  ");   
}
```

Comment: In the if you need to print indexes i and j.

Comment: Thank you. However, if I do that it'll only print the number right next to the number found. Finds 12 [here would be any out print within the if].

Answer (score 0):

As Heisenberg says, the first thing you need to do in order to print only the indexes that match the user's input, is to print the i and j indexes inside the if statement. Secondly, the way you have the print statement written currently will actually print the *value* of the index, when you want to print the actual index numbers. You'd do this by simply printing out `i` and `j`. I suggest to change it to this:

```
if(num == matriznx[i][j]){
  cont++;
  System.out.println("[" + i + "][" + j + "]");  //prints as "[0][4]", for example)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating an array of length width * height with a width of 2 and storing the coordinates found on line 15. ie

```
index = 0

if(num == matriznx[i][j]){
    cont++;
    coordinates[index][1] = j
    coordinates[index++][2] = i    
}
```

Then use a loop to print out the results at the end of the program.